# Delete a Mesh selected with a button in BabylonJs

Tags: mesh, babylonjs

This my code in the `Default.Html` Page:

```
<button id="Remove_mesh" class="group">Remove</button>
```

And this my **JS**:

```
var pickResult = scene.pick(offsetX, offsetY);
if (pickResult.pickedMesh) {
 if ($('Remove_mesh').click(function(){}))
 {
    pickResult.dispose();
 }
```

This didn't work

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: I find my error,  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use: pickResult.pickedMesh.dispose()

```
$('Remove_mesh').on("click", function () {
    pickResult.pickedMesh.dispose();
});
```

More info: http://doc.babylonjs.com/page.php?p=24938

Comment: Then something else is wrong. Did you check if pickResult.pickedMesh is not null?

Comment: I find my error, just a missing librairy...Sorry , thanks for you help.